# can't change drop-down mat-form-field CSS - Angular material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Im having an issue when I try to change the CSS of dropdown using mat-form-field of angular material in two things :

1. My CSS doesnt change the propertys `<option> and <optgroup>` .
2. cant change `:hover` CSS for `<option>`
3. the position ot the dropdown "cuts" the current selected option.

My dropdown style atm (default angular-material) :

[drop-down-atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agd9k.png)

The html :

```
<mat-form-field class="drop-down" appearance="fill">
  <select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="currentActiveModeValue" (change)="onModeChange($event)">
    <optgroup *ngFor="let mainModes of activeModArry; let i = index" label="{{ mainModes.name }}">
      <option *ngFor="let subModes of mainModes.childModes" [value]="subModes.id">
        {{ subModes.name }}
      </option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The style I wish to do :

[the drop-down I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il0bI.png)

Really need some help with that, If someone had this problem before :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe native dropdowns are not style-able. You can try to use the material select and add your own classes to be able to style it

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="my-class">
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="currentActiveModeValue" (change)="onModeChange($event)">
    <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let mainModes of activeModArry; let i = index" [label]="mainModes.name">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let subModes of mainModes.childModes" [value]="subModes.id">
        {{ subModes.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-optgroup>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Edit: You may need to use the `::ng-deep` selector to target the shadow elements that material generates.

Something like:

```
.mat-form-field ::ng-deep .mat-optgroup {
  // styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you work with some material angular components you need declare the styles "globlally". You can include in your file "styles.sccs"

```
.mat-optgroup-label {
    color:black;
    font-weight:600;
    border-bottom:1px solid silver;
}
.mat-optgroup .mat-option:not(.mat-option-multiple) {
    padding-left: 0!important;
}
.mat-option-text {
    border-bottom:1px solid silver;
    padding-left:32px;
}
```

The reason is that some Angular components create the "popup" outsite our component. You can see it in a div called `cdk-overlay-container`. This components has a property `panelClass` that allow us only change the css of only this component. That's. In your styles.scss you replace the before .css by -I used "special", you use the word you want

```
.special .mat-optgroup-label {
    color:black;
    font-weight:600;
    border-bottom:1px solid silver;
}
.special .mat-optgroup .mat-option:not(.mat-option-multiple) {
    padding-left: 0!important;
}
.special .mat-option-text {
    border-bottom:1px solid silver;
    padding-left:32px;
}
```

And in your select

```
<mat-select panelClass="special" ...>
  ...
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, for the hover to work you must use the material elements and then in the css use the `::ng-deep`, also verify that it does not have encapsulation set, in the component's .ts in the `@Component`.

In the html it would look like this:

```
<mat-form-field class="drop-down" appearance="fill">
    <mat-select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="currentActiveModeValue" (change)="onModeChange($event)">
      <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let mainModes of activeModArry; let i = index" label="{{ mainModes.name }}">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let subModes of mainModes.childModes" [value]="subModes.id">
          {{ subModes.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-optgroup>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

and the css would be like this

```
::ng-deep mat-option:hover {
  ...
}
```